# Copying non-app.config configuration files to output

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, configuration, log4net, configuration-files

I've recently moved our configuration for log4net out of the app.config of our services. It's now in one config file in a common assembly which we add as a link to all our services.

The aim is that developers will only have to edit the configuration in one place to affect all of the services but when we go to produce the application the user will get a config file for each service so they can edit them all independently.

Currently from the developer perspective this all works. From a user perspective no logging configuration is being copied to the bin directory so there's no way to edit the logging. Ideally, the logging configs would be copied/renamed like the app.config files are.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the "Copy to output directory" property of the file:

[image]